# Fixed by workaround: Static link stdc++.so to binary on solaris

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I'm compiling zeromq on solaris with gcc 4.8.  After the compiling,  I found the libzeromq.so is dependence on

```
  -bash-3.2$ ldd /export/home/zhifan/zeromq_s2/lib/libzmq.so
        ...
        libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libgcc_s.so.1
        ...
```

but since I don't have /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6 installed on other machines,  so I want to use statics link for /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6.

I tried the following ways, but no one works.

**Method 1:**

```
  ./configure  ... LDFLAGS='-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
```

**Method 2:**

```
  export LDFALGS='-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
  ./configure
```

**Method 3:**

```
 ./configure  ... LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++ LDFALGS=-static-libgcc
```

I can see the following lines in the generated Makefile.

```
LDFLAGS = -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

All the try failed since after my compile,

```
  ldd /export/home/zhifan/zeromq_s2/lib/libzmq.so
        ...
        libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libgcc_s.so.1
        ...
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

**My Env**

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: sparc64-sun-solaris2.10
Configured with: /home/zhifan/gcc-4.8.2/configure --build=sparc64-sun-solaris2.10 --prefix=/usr/local
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
-bash-3.2$ uname -a
SunOS xxx 5.10 Generic_147440-09 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

**Another Test shows my env support the 2 options**

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ 1.cc -o 1
-bash-3.2$ ldd 1
        libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
        /lib/sparcv9/../libm/sparcv9/libm_hwcap1.so.2
        /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
-bash-3.2$ g++ 1.cc -o 1 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
-bash-3.2$ ldd 1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/64/libc.so.1
        /lib/sparcv9/../libm/sparcv9/libm_hwcap1.so.2
        /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
```

**My questions are**

1. How to fix this issue?
2. during the compile,  How can I see the LDFLAGS it use? currently it is something like

   ```
     CXX    local_lat.o
     CXXLD  local_lat
   ```

   TO

   `CXXLD  local_lat -L ... -l...`

   so that I can see if the LDFLAGS used.

   ***Answer for Q2:***

   make -n

   will show the linker options, here is an example.

   echo "  CXXLD " libzmq.la;/bin/bash ../libtool --silent --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -fvisibility=hidden  -g -O2 -version-info 3:0:0  ***-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc*** -o libzmq.la -rpath /export/home/zhifan/zeromq3/lib libzmq_la-address.lo libzmq_la-clock.lo libzmq_la-ctx.lo libzmq_la-decoder.lo libzmq_la-devpoll.lo libzmq_la-dist.lo libzmq_la-encoder.lo libzmq_la-epoll.lo libzmq_la-err.lo libzmq_la-fq.lo libzmq_la-io_object.lo libzmq_la-io_thread.lo libzmq_la-ip.lo libzmq_la-ipc_address.lo libzmq_la-ipc_connecter.lo libzmq_la-ipc_listener.lo libzmq_la-kqueue.lo libzmq_la-lb.lo libzmq_la-mailbox.lo libzmq_la-msg.lo libzmq_la-mtrie.lo libzmq_la-object.lo libzmq_la-options.lo libzmq_la-own.lo libzmq_la-pair.lo libzmq_la-pgm_receiver.lo libzmq_la-pgm_sender.lo libzmq_la-pgm_socket.lo libzmq_la-pipe.lo libzmq_la-poll.lo libzmq_la-poller_base.lo libzmq_la-pull.lo libzmq_la-push.lo libzmq_la-proxy.lo libzmq_la-reaper.lo libzmq_la-pub.lo libzmq_la-random.lo libzmq_la-rep.lo libzmq_la-req.lo libzmq_la-select.lo libzmq_la-session_base.lo libzmq_la-signaler.lo libzmq_la-socket_base.lo libzmq_la-stream_engine.lo libzmq_la-sub.lo libzmq_la-tcp.lo libzmq_la-tcp_address.lo libzmq_la-tcp_connecter.lo libzmq_la-tcp_listener.lo libzmq_la-thread.lo libzmq_la-trie.lo libzmq_la-xpub.lo libzmq_la-router.lo libzmq_la-dealer.lo libzmq_la-v1_decoder.lo libzmq_la-v1_encoder.lo libzmq_la-xsub.lo libzmq_la-zmq.lo libzmq_la-zmq_utils.lo  -lnsl -lsocket -lrt -lpthread

***Final Soluation***

I packaged all the needed libraries, and shipped them to other machines.  This way works.

Comment: Perhaps if you spell `LDFLAGS` correctly some of the problems might just go away (no guarantees).

Comment: @n.m.  Thanks for your reply. I fixed this error, but still no lucky:(

Comment: Did you finally managed to fix this issue? I'm trying to statically link libstdc++ (on many different unix/posix platforms), tried all flags and still no luck, ldd shows linking to /usr/lib.